# WeatherData for visibility seems to be missing

Tags: curated-data

When I explore the document of `WeatherData` of wolfram document center. It is said that `WeatherData` has properties of visibility. But when I doing it in mathematica, it seems can not get the value of different places.

```
In[5] := WeatherData["Singapore", "Visibility"]
Out[5] = Missing["NotAvailable"]
In[6] := WeatherData["Singapore", "Pressure"]
Out[6] = Quantity[1011, "Millibars"]
In[7] := WeatherData["Singapore", "Temperature"]
Out[7] = Quantity[30., "DegreesCelsius"]
In[8] := WeatherData["Shanghai", "Visibility"]
Out[8] = Missing["NotAvailable"]
In[9] := WeatherData["Beijing", "Visibility"]
Out[9] = Missing["NotAvailable"]
In[10]:= WeatherData["Beijing", "Temperature"]
Out[10] = Quantity[22., "DegreesCelsius"]
In[11] := WeatherData["NewYork", "Visibility"]
Out[11] = Missing["NotAvailable"]
In[12] := WeatherData["NewYork", "Temperature"]
Out[12] = Quantity[20., "DegreesCelsius"]
```

So the data of visibility seems to be missing for variable cities. Is it removed from the current version of Mathematica or can anyone get the visibility data of these cities?

I am using Mathematica version 10.0.1

[WeatherData Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeatherData.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem appears to be that you asking for visibility data for the exact moment you are evaluating `WeatherData` and such data were not yet available. If you were to ask for historical data, say for this month, you would get results.

```
visibility = WeatherData["NewYork", "Visibility", {2015, 9}]
```

[image: visibility]

The above is hourly data from several stations in New York, so I reduce the data by selection the first midnight data point.

```
daily = 
  First /@ 
    Gather[Normal /@ Normal[visibility], Take[First[#1], 3] == Take[First[#2], 3] &]
```

> ```
> {{{2015, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[16, "Kilometers"]}, 
>  {{2015, 9, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[16, "Kilometers"]}, 
>  {{2015, 9, 3, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[16, "Kilometers"]}, 
>  {{2015, 9, 4, 0, 51, 0.}, Quantity[16.093, "Kilometers"]}, 
>  {{2015, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[16, "Kilometers"]}, 
>  {{2015, 9, 6, 0, 51, 0.}, Quantity[16.093, "Kilometers"]}, 
>  {{2015, 9, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[16, "Kilometers"]}, 
>  {{2015, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[16, "Kilometers"]}, 
>  {{2015, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[16, "Kilometers"]}, 
>  {{2015, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[16, "Kilometers"]}, 
>  {{2015, 9, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[12, "Kilometers"]}, 
>  {{2015, 9, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[16, "Kilometers"]}, 
>  ...
>  {{2015, 9, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, Quantity[16, "Kilometers"]},
>  {{2015, 9, 20, 0, 3, 0.}, Missing["NotAvailable"]}, 
>  {{2015, 9, 21, 0, 51, 0.}, Missing["NotAvailable"]}}
> ```

From this, except for the 11th, it looks like New York city had clear skies for September and that the data for 20th and 21st is not available yet.